# JS datetime to PHP conversion

Tags: php, javascript, datetime

how can i convert datetime from JS return by this function

```
var now = new Date();
output:  Sun Feb 24 2013 01:26:47 GMT+0800 (MYT)
```

into php readable format such as `date(YmdHis)` ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @MarshallHouse: http://w3fools.com

Comment: @MarcB That site seems like an over reaction really. If they have bad information it's probably fine details and i'll get over it. Not like you can trust other blogs any better. w3schools is pretty handy and i haven't had problems except lack of elaboration sometimes (with PHP mostly). I always use php.net now. but for js.. where else?

Comment: @MarshallHouse: MDN ! It's very accurate and complete

Answer (score 1):

Return a UNIX timestamp from your Javascript function:

```
Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) //returns number of seconds since epoch
```

Then simply use that in PHPs date function:

```
$yourJsTime = $_GET['jsTime']; //depends on how you pass your js timestamp
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('YmdHis', $yourJsTime);
```